# Limit of $x^5\cos\left(\frac1x\right)$ as $x$ approaches $0$

Tags: limits

Find the limit of $x^5\cos\left(\frac1x\right)$ as $x$ approaches $0$.
Can I just substitute $0$ to $x^5$? But what would be $\cos\left(\frac10\right)$ be?

I could solve for $-x^4\le x^4\cos(1/x)\leq x^4$
in which limit of $x^4$ is and $-x^4=0$ and by sandwich theorem limit=0
but is there a method to solve it without doing so

Comment: You can't substitute $0$ for $x$, you expression doesn't make sense when $x=0$. That's why you're taking the limit

Comment: Division by $0$ is undefined, so you can't just substitute, you need another method....

Comment: look up squeeze theorem.

Comment: Well, sandwich method seems the easiest, most natural and direct way to do it. Perhaps even the only one.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is zero because it is "zero$\times$ bounded "=$0$

$x^5\to 0$ when $x\to 0$ and

$$-1\leq \cos (1/x) \leq 1$$

$\cos(1/x)$ is bounded

---

A zero-bounded limit is one in which the function can be broken
into a product of two functions where one function converges to zero and the other
function is bounded. If we show that a limit is zero -bounded, then the zero-bounded
limit theorem implies that the limit goes to zero.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the function to exist at $0$ for the limit to exist. And, $\frac 10$ does not exist.

However, you have $\left|\cos \right|<2$, thus $\left|x^5\cos{\frac 1x}\right|<2|x|^5$

Can you go from here?

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $-1\le \cos \left(\frac 1x\right)\le 1\ \ \forall  \ \ x\in \mathbb{R}$, hence 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^5\cos\left(\frac 1x\right)=0$$

Comment: squeeze theorem, I presume?